# Photoshop image blending mode in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, photoshop, blending

After a lot of searching now i am able to create Photoshop blending mode filter in android.  Here is my working code for image blending mode in android it is working from android 2.1 to 4.4 enjoy and incase of any query feel free to ask :)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnLoadImage1, btnLoadImage2;
    TextView textSource1, textSource2;
    Button btnProcessing;
    ImageView imageResult;

    final int RQS_IMAGE1 = 1;
    final int RQS_IMAGE2 = 2;
    int blendmode=1;
    Uri source1, source2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnLoadImage1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadimage1);
        btnLoadImage2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadimage2);
        textSource1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sourceuri1);
        textSource2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sourceuri2);
        btnProcessing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.processing);
        imageResult = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        /*
        SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.businnes);
        Picture picture = svg.getPicture();
        Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
        imageResult.setImageDrawable(drawable);*/
        btnLoadImage1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_IMAGE1);
            }
        });

        btnLoadImage2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_IMAGE2);
            }
        });

        btnProcessing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (source1 != null && source2 != null) {
                    Bitmap processedBitmap = ProcessingBitmap(blendmode);
                    blendmode++;
                    if(blendmode>7)
                        blendmode=1;
                    if (processedBitmap != null) {
                        imageResult.setImageBitmap(processedBitmap);
                        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Something wrong in processing!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Select both image!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case RQS_IMAGE1:
                source1 = data.getData();
                textSource1.setText(source1.toString());
                break;
            case RQS_IMAGE2:
                source2 = data.getData();
                textSource2.setText(source2.toString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private Bitmap ProcessingBitmap(int value) {
        Bitmap bm1 = null;
        Bitmap bm2 = null;
        Bitmap newBitmap = null;

        try {
            bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(source1));
            bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(source2));

            int w;
            if (bm1.getWidth() >= bm2.getWidth()) {
                w = bm1.getWidth();
            } else {
                w = bm2.getWidth();
            }

            int h;
            if (bm1.getHeight() >= bm2.getHeight()) {
                h = bm1.getHeight();
            } else {
                h = bm2.getHeight();
            }

            Config config = bm1.getConfig();
            if (config == null) {
                config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            }



            newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, config);
            Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);

            newCanvas.drawBitmap(bm1, 0, 0, null);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            switch (value) {
            case Key.KEYS_BLEND_DARKEN:
                Print_Toast("BLEND_DARKEN");
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DARKEN));
                break;
            case Key.KEYS_BLEND_MULTIPLY:
                Print_Toast("BLEND_MULTIPLY");
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));
                break;
            case Key.KEYS_BLEND_ADD:
                Print_Toast("BLEND_ADD");
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.ADD));
                break;
            case Key.KEYS_BLEND_DESOLVE:
                Print_Toast("BLEND_DESOLVE");
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST));
                break;

            case Key.KEYS_BLEND_DESOLVE_LIGHTEN:
                Print_Toast("BLEND_LIGHTEN");
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.LIGHTEN));
                break;
            case Key.KEYS_BLEND_DESOLVE_OVERLAY:

                Print_Toast("BLEND_OVERLAY");
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.OVERLAY));
                break;
            case Key.KEYS_BLEND_DESOLVE_SCREEN:
                Print_Toast("BLEND_SCREEN");
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SCREEN));
                break;


            default:
                break;
            }

            paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bm2, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP));
            /*paint.setAlpha(128);
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);*/
            //paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
            newCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, bm2.getWidth(), bm2.getHeight(), paint);
            //newCanvas.drawBitmap(bm2, 0, 0, paint);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return newBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    void printlog(String tag,String value){
        Log.d(tag, value);
    }
    void Print_Toast(String value){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here is **Key class**

```
public class Key {
    final public static int KEYS_BLEND_DARKEN=1;
    final public static int KEYS_BLEND_MULTIPLY=2;;
    public static final int KEYS_BLEND_ADD = 3;
    public static final int KEYS_BLEND_DESOLVE = 4;
    public static final int KEYS_BLEND_DESOLVE_LIGHTEN = 5;
    public static final int KEYS_BLEND_DESOLVE_OVERLAY = 6;
    public static final int KEYS_BLEND_DESOLVE_SCREEN = 7;

}
```

xml file is **activity_main**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loadimage1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Load Image1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sourceuri1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loadimage1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loadimage1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loadimage2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loadimage1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sourceuri1"
            android:text="Load Image2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sourceuri2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sourceuri1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/loadimage2"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/processing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loadimage2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/loadimage2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sourceuri2"
            android:text="Processing" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/processing"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. but i am getting errors on switch case where Key.KEYS_BLEND_MULTIPLY:

Comment: ok you have to add new class name as keys well check the update version i just make some edits in code just add class name as Key ok then your problem is solved

Comment: Yes. After looking into code i observed that values are 1 to 7. and i added those values. anyway thank you. @Hafiz.M.Usman